# Is there a way to reference the User Model before the user is Authenticated from the LoginController, in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am trying to overwrite the attemptLogin function in the LoginController, so that I can accept an old password then force a password reset using middlewear after the login authentication.

I have functionality in the "User" Model that pulls their old password so I can check it and Authenticate it if their main/new password fails or they don't have a main/new password. My only problem is trying to reference the user from within the function, because one isn't instantiated, yet.

Is there a way to call to the model's functionality without passing an Authenticated guard response first using the given Username.

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{

    // Standard LoginController Stuff...


    protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {
        if (!$this->guard()->attempt(
            $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember'))) {
            $user = Auth::user();   //<--- This doesn't work, the User hasn't been Authenticated yet.
            $md5Hash = md5($this->credentials($request)['password']);
            if ($md5Hash === $user->getOldPass()) 
                return true;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to load the `User` model yourself.

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    if ($this->guard()->attempt($this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember'))) {
        return true;
    }

    if (!$user = User::where($this->username(), $request->input($this->username()))->first()) {
        return false;
    }

    if (md5($request->input('password')) === $user->getOldPass()) {
        $this->guard()->login($user, $request->filled('remember'));

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: That's Perfect, thank you. The only thing I did differently is that I left off the second parameter on --> $this->guard()->login($user, $request->filled('remember'));  Because I don't want the old password to be saved/remembered when it is used, because it will be reset anyway.